# Windows Hello shows error when I try to setup a new account

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-hello

I have a laptop that was connected to my old company's AD and an account with Windows Hello configured.

Yesterday I disconnected the laptop from that AD and defined a new Azure AD work account that I want to use windows hello, but when I try to setup the face recognition it shows an error saying that there is another account configured and I should remove face recognition from it first. But that old account was removed when I disconnected Windows from the old directory and the referred account doesn't even exist anymore. I think windows might kept the face recognition setup for that account and I cant find how to remove it.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: win hello error]

Answer (score 1):

Solved... The domain user was removed from windows but its profile was kept. When I managed to completely remove it from the computer, the face recognition started to work again. Here's how I did it:

Win + R > sysdm.cpl > Advanced > User Profiles > Settings

Then I selected the "Unknow Account" listed and removed it hitting Delete.

After that, I went back to Windows Hello setup and worked like a charm.

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, an old account with "leftovers" can cause this problem (in my case during laptop setup, my username has been shorten, and recreating it caused this issue)

Use elevated PowerShell with the command

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile
```

Identify with **LocalPath** an old account name, for the example '**UserA**', **to be replaced in below cmd**, then run :

```
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq 'UserA' } | Remove-CimInstance`
```

credits : [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2281901-server-2016-sysdm-cpl-user-profiles)